# Browser doesn't show Arabic fonts correctly

Tags: html, css, encoding, fonts, arabic

This is my herokuapp: https://majeddh.herokuapp.com; I'm using it to test the fonts right now.

This is my HTML code:

```
<?php echo 'majed'?><html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>

<style>
    @import url('lateef.css');

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Lateef';
    }

    .wf-active h1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    h2{
    font-family:'lateef1';}
</style>

<body>
<h1>This headline will be hidden until Droid Sans is completely loaded.</h1>
<h1>ماجد</h1>
<h2>This headline will be hidden until Droid Sans is completely loaded.</h2>
<h2>ماجد</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
      /*this is arabic*/
  font-family: 'Lateef';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://majeddh.herokuapp.com/FS_Metal2.TTF) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
       /*this is english*/
  font-family: 'Lateef1';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://majeddh.herokuapp.com/FS_Metal1.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

I don't know where the problem is; English fonts appear but Arabic don't, and I've tried with 3 different fonts and the same problem appears.

Comment: Lateef1 works for me and Lateef doesn't. Are you sure Lateef has the right codepoints? Arabic must be way up there in the unicode table and Lateef must have those points.

Answer (score 2):

The font called “Lateef1” in the code is actually Baroque Script, and it does not contain any Arabic letters. The font called “Lateef” is Lucida Grande, but for some reason, it is not used even for English letters on the page. This might be caused by some checks against unlicensed usage. You should check whether you can legally use the fonts as downloadable fonts; this requires a permission from copyright holders.

Answer (score 1):

When I access your page with Firefox, the Firebug console says:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://majeddh.herokuapp.com/FS_Metal2.ttf"

This seems to explain it all – the font file is missing (on the server).